# MySQL query needed for mixed order by statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema of a MySQL table (simplified), which has an index field that encapsulates the hierarchy of
comment entries in a whole comment thread.

```
+----------+------------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | INTEGER    | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| comment  | TEXT       |     | NULL    |                |
| index    | TEXT       |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------+-----+---------+----------------+

id: comment:                         index:
-------------------------------------------------------
1   Rootentry1                        1
2   Answer1 on Rootentry1             1.1
3   Rootentry2                        2
4   Answer1 on Answer1 on Rootentry1  1.1.1
5   Rootentry3                        3
6   Answer1 on Rootentry2             2.1
7   Answer2 on Rootentry1             1.2
```

Now I would like to sort the table in a way that the latest `Rootentry` appears first.
The Result should be in following order:

```
id: comment:                         index:
------------------------------------------------------
5   Rootentry3                       3
3   Rootentry2                       2
6   Answer1 on Rootentry2            2.1
1   Rootentry1                       1
2   Answer1 on Rootentry1            1.1
4   Answer1 on Answer1 on Rootentry1 1.1.1
7   Answer2 on Rootentry1            1.2
```

I need a sort algorithm that sorts the first index in a Descending way and the following chars in a Ascending way
What is the statement for sorting the entries like this?

Comment: This is going to be tricky. You will want to split the "index" by the dot and cast it to an integer, because if you use alphanumeric sorting 10 will come before 2.

Comment: Do you have a maximum level of comment nesting? Do you need to show all the comments at once, or could you get away with loading answers/replies lazily beyond a certain depth?

Comment: @Bart Friederichs: Right, but thats just one of the tricky stuff. Because the major index has to be sorted descending, and all the minor-indexes need to be sorted ascending. Do you or anybody else known a solution to solve this problem with a query without to create an additional column for the major index?

Comment: @Arth: I have all comments available , without lazy loading. In reality there will be not more than 10 levels. But currently I have no technical constraints regarding the level. But I can limit the levels. Its not the major part of my problem, but important to, i agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
*
from table1
order by 
cast(substring_index(`index`, '.', 1) as unsigned) desc,
substring(`index`, 2+length(substring_index(`index`, '.', 1))) asc
```

Output:

```
id  comment                             index
5   Rootentry3                          3
3   Rootentry2                          2
6   Answer1 on Rootentry2               2.1
1   Rootentry1                          1
2   Answer1 on Rootentry1               1.1
4   Answer1 on Answer1 on Rootentry1    1.1.1
7   Answer2 on Rootentry1               1.2
```

Comment: hi Grzegorz. 
Thanks for your input! Unfortunately in android mysql there are no functions like substring_index and substring. there are other substr functions available. I think the solution has to be build with one of those functions : [link:](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

Comment: With your Input I was almost able to find a solution:
`code`
select * FROM table_comment ORDER BY cast(substr(`threadIndex`, 1,ifnull(nullif(instr(`threadIndex`,'.')-1,-1),length(`threadIndex`))) as unsigned) desc, substr(`threadIndex`, instr(`threadIndex`,'.')+1) asc `code` now it is working up to 9 subcomments then the problem occurs that when sorting a string desc "10" appears before "2" . For indexes e.g. like 2.10.1.1  compared to 2.2.1.1. I sould recoursively search for index delimeter like "." and cast them to integers... its very tricky...

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,legal VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO my_table (legal) VALUES ('1'),('1.1'),('2'),('1.1.1'),('3'),('2.1'),('1.2');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-------+
| id | legal |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 1     |
|  2 | 1.1   |
|  4 | 1.1.1 |
|  7 | 1.2   |
|  3 | 2     |
|  6 | 2.1   |
|  5 | 3     |
+----+-------+

SELECT *
     , FLOOR(INET_ATON(RPAD(legal,5,'.0'))/16000000) x -- or perhaps 16777216
  FROM my_table 
 ORDER 
    BY x DESC
     , legal;
+----+-------+------+
| id | legal | x    |
+----+-------+------+
|  5 | 3     |    3 |
|  3 | 2     |    2 |
|  6 | 2.1   |    2 |
|  1 | 1     |    1 |
|  2 | 1.1   |    1 |
|  4 | 1.1.1 |    1 |
|  7 | 1.2   |    1 |
+----+-------+------+
```